# How to use location with subfolder in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

There is the following config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name some-site.io;

  root /srv/projects/folder/public;

  location /view {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

In '/srv/projects/folder/public' there is folder view with files like 'app.js', 'app.css' and so on. I want that this config catches requests like 'some-site.io/view/app.js' and returns app.js file from '/srv/projects/folder/public/view' folder; for 'some-site.io/view' requests I'd like to get index file from '/srv/projects/folder/public/view' folder. Right now I get 404 for 'some-site.io/view' request and I don't understand why.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need the location section at all? You say that requests to the /view path should be sent the view folder inside the document root. This sounds like the default behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to find index files using a URI without a trailing `/`, use `$uri/index.html`. By using `/index.html` it is always looking in the parent directory for `index.html`.